# Unable to connect to openstack instance using NoVNC console

Tags: instance, openstack

While trying to access to instances via NoVNC console from other nodes such as storage and compute connection at 127.0.0.1:6080 cannot be established but everything works well on the controller node.
Still looking for the missing configuration

Answer (score 0):

this IP '127.0.0.1' is a localhost IP, which means that this IP can resolve from the server on that server and another server, 127.0.0.1 point to a different destination.
you should run noVNC on some IP from the network and you can configure this at `/etc/kolla/nova-novncproxy/nova.conf`